# How to upload file or image from django oscar dashboard?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-oscar

So, I tried to modify ProductClass from Django Oscar. 
It works fine if I tried to upload image from Django Rest API, like below:

[image]

But when I tried to upload image from Django Oscar admin dashboard it always return null.

[image]

Here is my model:

[image]

Here is my view:
[image]

And below is my dashboard/catalogue/forms.py

[image]

What do I need to modify or extends so that I can upload image using Django Oscar admin dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any views.py preview for your customization it's quite hard to explain and solve your problem. But I would explain how you can fork or customize any django oscar app/ model/ view.

In order to customize models, views and urls, you need to fork an Oscar core app in which model/view resides. Then you should be able to override any model/view classes.

Steps to fork/customize an app:

1. If you are forking an Oscar app for the first time, then you have to create a root apps-folder in which all your forked apps will exists:

   $ mkdir yourappsfolder
   $ touch yourappsfolder/**init**.py
2. Create a python module with the same ‘app-label’ as the Oscar app:

Ex: Customising oscar.apps.catalogue app

```
$ mkdir yourappsfolder/catalogue
$ touch yourappsfolder/catalogue/__init__.py
```

3. If the Oscar app has a models.py, then you have to create a models.py file in your local app.

   ## your custom models go here

   from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *

NOTE: To customise Oscar’s models, you must add your custom one before importing Oscar’s models. Then, your models file will have two models with the same name within an app, Django will only use the first one.

Ex: To add a active field to the product model:

```
# yourappsfolder/catalogue/models.py
from django.db import models
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct
class Product(AbstractProduct):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

4. Create an ‘admin.py’ file in your local app.

   ## yourappsfolder/catalogue/admin.py

   from oscar.apps.catalogue.admin import *
5. Then copy the ‘migrations’ directory from oscar/apps/catalogue and put it into your new local catalogue app.
6. Added it as Django app by replacing Oscar’s app with your own in INSTALLED_APPS.

   ## settings.py

   from oscar import get_core_apps
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       ...,
       # all your non-Oscar apps
   ] + get_core_apps(['yourappsfolder.catalogue'])

NOTE: get_core_apps([]) will return a list of Oscar core apps or else if you give a list of your custom apps, they will replace the Oscar core apps.

7. Finally, create migrations using ‘makemigrations’ management command and apply the migrations by using ‘migrate catalogue’ management command. Then, you can see that a new column is been added to the product model.

Steps for customizing URL’s:

1. Follow the same above steps described in customizing an app.
2. In Oscar, each app will have its own URLs in the ‘app.py’ file and each app comes with an application instance with ‘urls’ property, which used to access the list of URL’s of an app.

   - Modify ‘yourproject/urls.py’ file to include Oscar URL’s.

     from django.conf.urls import include, url
     from yourproject.app import application
     urlpatterns = [
        # Your other URLs
        url(r'', include(application.urls)),
     ]
3. To change the URL for the basket app from ‘basket’ to ‘cart’, you need to customize root app instance by creating a sub-class of it and overriding the ‘get_urls’ method.

   ## yourproject/app.py

   from oscar import app
   class Shop(app.Shop):
       def get_urls(self):
           urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^cart/', include(self.basket_app.urls)),
               # ...
               # Remianing urls here
           ]
           return urlpatterns
   application = Shop()

Steps for customizing or adding views to an app:

1. Follow the same above steps described in customizing an app.
2. Create a new view class or create a sub-class of Oscar’s view in views.py file:

Ex: Add extra context to the home page.

```
from oscar.apps.promotions.views import HomeView as CoreHomeView
class HomeView(CoreHomeView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["latest_products"] = Product.objects.filter(
            parent=None).order_by('-date_created')
        return context
```

Please keep in mind that you don't need to import all(*) from django oscar app here in views.

This help I got from MicroPyramid blog.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. I don't have problem on how to extend django oscar. My problem is specific to the image. So, I add new FileField on ProductClass but it always failed when I save ProductClass data from django oscar dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this view class to upload from django oscar dashboard like above described -

```
class ProductCreateUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
```

it is located here.

```
oscar/apps/dashboard/catalogue/views.py
```

Comment: I already did that too, I did that to remove one of the formset when saving product. What function do i need to override?

Comment: And my issue happens on ProductClass not Product

Answer (score 0):

Oscar's `ImageInput` is a rather specific widget that is intended only to work with a formset of images - as on the product edit form. It relies on Javascript to correctly populate the input field's value when an image is selected. That Javascript will not work outside of a formset.

You are probably better off just using the default widget in this case.

If you do want the ability to display a preview of the selected image (which is all that the `ImageInput` adds really), then you will need to write a custom widget that does this. The relevant JS for doing so is here: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/b627fa7954d284190cfe7c8c75da0528a6dd6bf7/src/oscar/static/oscar/js/oscar/dashboard.js#L7-L14

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem, after adding the fields in the model, I had to edit the form of the Product class template located in templates/oscar/dashboard/catalogue/product_class_form.html. I just added : enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form.

With that, the image gets saved correctly :).